# Confused with laravel relationship controllers

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller

Using the Users/Posts relationship example from the Laravel Docs as an example, I can't wrap my head around the best way to organise my controllers for a Users Posts.

In this project, posts will only be accessible through either a user or a Post List, e.g /username/postname or /listname/postname, there will be no direct URL to a post without the user/list as well. And the posts slug/url does not have to be globally unique, just unique to the user/list, so the controller will always have to accept a User/List and a Slug parameter.

So I can't decide how to organise my controllers, should I have:

a) UserController, ListController, PostController
b) UserController, ListController, PostController, UserPostController, ListPostController
c) UserController, ListPostController and UserPostController

or some other arrangement?

There are arguments for all 3, and I can't quite settle on any solution.

With a, it feels a bit unintuitive that every method requires a User/List slug as well, and it will always be accessed in relation to a User/List

with b, it seems a bit excessive when PostController won't really have many methods apart from 'Create' (which I feel should just be at /posts/create, rather than /username/create or /listname/create)

with c, as above I feel that Create is not a part of the UserPost/ListPost flow, and is just a part of the Post flow really. Because Posts will be accessed through 2 relations, it feels wrong to tie it to one of them or duplicate it.

Hopefully this makes an ounce of sense to someone

Comment: Any chance the username and the listname are the same? How do you differentiate which it is if you get something like `list/post-0` or something?

Comment: I didn't want to complicate my question further, but lists will actually be owned by users so the hierarchy will be /user/list/post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach to this is having only two controllers ..

`UserController` and `ListController` ..

> Having a Model Post doesn't mean you have to have `PostController` too .. you can just `use App\Post` in the two controllers above.

assuming they're related to post .. you can create post using them ..

```
$post = $user->posts()->create([
    'title' => 'hmm',
    'body'  => 'blaah',
]);
```

or

```
$post = New Post($data);
$post = $list->posts()->save($post);
```

Comment: Sounds sensible, I think i'll go with this, It alleviates most worries I had.